# Using Arrow Function with addEventListener gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined at onChangeHandler

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, hoisting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Essentials</title>


  <style>

   * {
    text-align: center;
   }

   /*.car-display {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
   }*/

  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <select id="mySelect" name="cars">
   <option disabled selected='selected'>Select your option</option> <!-- try with aventador as the starting one -->
   <option value="Lamborghini Aventador">Lamborghini Aventador</option>
   <option value="Ferarri LaFerarri">Ferarri LaFerarri</option>
   <option value="McLaren LP">McLaren LP</option>
   <option value="Audi R8">Audi R8</option>

  </select>

  
  </div>

   <div class="test">
   <div>djfh</div>
   <p>sdjfdf</p>
   <h3>djshf</h3>
  </div>  Also try to dynamically add the pics below here

  <div id="picture">

  </div>

  <script src="myapp4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make use of the arrow functions but it gives me an error. It doesn't give an error when I define my function like this: **function onChangeHandler() {...}** why is that?
I've also tried this: 
options.addEventListener('change',onChangeHandler.bind(this); But it also doesn't work. What is the correct method?

Also arrow functions aren't hoisted right?

```js
    var select = document.getElementsByName('cars');

    const options = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var picture = document.getElementById("picture");

    options.addEventListener('change',onChangeHandler);

    onChangeHandler = () => {
     var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
     console.log(value);
     picture.innerHTML = '<img name="image" src="images/' + value + '.jpg">';

     var img = document.getElementsByName("image")[0].style.cssText='width: 800px; height: 400px';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Essentials</title>


  <style>

   * {
    text-align: center;
   }

   /*.car-display {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
   }*/

  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <select id="mySelect" name="cars">
   <option disabled selected='selected'>Select your option</option> <!-- try with aventador as the starting one -->
   <option value="Lamborghini Aventador">Lamborghini Aventador</option>
   <option value="Ferarri LaFerarri">Ferarri LaFerarri</option>
   <option value="McLaren LP">McLaren LP</option>
   <option value="Audi R8">Audi R8</option>

  </select>

  <div id="picture">

  </div>

  <script src="myapp4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a value to `onChangeHandler` **before** you try to read that value by passing `onChangeHandler` to `addEventListener`.

Assignments are not hoisted.

Comment: It looks like the order is correct in OP's real code, the error message comes from insde the function (`this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

your options variable is null. are you sure you have an element with id `mySelect` and have waited for the page to load before executing your javascript?

Comment: The options variable is null because the live demo is missing its HTML (which makes it a terrible live demo). I don't think that is the error the question is asking about.

Comment: I'm aware. I was socratically guiding OP to write better questions

Comment: Then use a comment. Don't use answers to comment about problems that aren't what the question is about.

Comment: that's a fair point

Comment: Sorry, I added the HTML. But someone suggested an answer from a different post so I'll take a look at that.